# USB memory stick undetected by Samsung Galaxy G5 Mini

Tags: usb-connection-mode, samsung-galaxy-s-5

According to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XeMW0NHGOxg) on YouTube, I should be able to connect a USB memory stick directly to my Samsung G5 Mini, and the phone should automatically detect it. But if I try this with a USB 2 memory stick and cable, my phone does not detect it?

Why? Can anyone advise?

My phone runs Android 4.4.2 and is a model SM: G800F.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have an OTG cable, but you also need to download and install an OTG driver.  I think I found mine on the Samsung website, in the phone download section.

Comment: Are you sure that there is such a driver for the G5 Mini? If I understand it correctly, according to http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s5-mini/help/usb-host-otg-t2855675 there is no such facility on the G5 Mini.